# How do I save a Word document in color, as a monochrome Word document?

Tags: microsoft-word

I always use [color that assists me](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/110315/13306) when preparing Word documents, but I must submit them in monochrome as SOLELY a Word document. Please rule out PDFs and other formats.

Just clicking <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, then choose Black can fail, e.g. for Excel imports and pictures that would remain in color.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want a quick way to make all images greyscale, and all text black? And you want the Excel icon to show in greyscale too, when you've embedded an Excel workbook?

Comment: If you press Ctrl+A and apply black font color, this will only change all body text color to black. If Print to PDF in black and white isn't an option, since there is no such build-in feature in Word to change the page color to black and white. You may need to manually modify images and table colors one by one.  I think there may be a solution using VBA but I don't work it out.

Comment: @spikey_richie yes